# Recommended maximum number of HTML elements on a page

Tags: html, performance, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a custom search using the fantastic jQuery plugin [Filtrify](http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/).

The client has added a great deal more content than we initially expected, and now there are over well 5 000 HTML elements on the page.

My question: is there a recommendation for the maximum number of HTML elements on a page?

The page is still rendering - and the jQuery filtering still works well - but I'm worried about it tapping out at some stage in the future if they add even more data.

Comment: The more elements, the more RAM will be used by the browser.

Comment: Being worried is okay, however there is no hard-limit but it depends on the computer displaying the website. Just signal your customer they can't stuff it into oblivion here and you should be fine for the project.

Answer (score 3):

Any problems would be purely performance related. Many factors would go into finding a maximum number of elements without sacrificing performance. Multiple pages (http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/jpages.html) will help the browser from using too much memory.